# What is a good intermediate-to-advanced ASP.NET MVC 2 book?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC, but I have developed a couple of simple applications using it, so I am not completely new. I have gone through the majority of tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc and I have read the "Professional ASP.NET MVC2 (Wrox)" book by the guys over at Microsoft. I have also done some extensive reading on DDD, TDD, and Repository patterns.

I am interested in moving beyond the basics of MVC and getting more in-depth into best practices, specifically relating to EF4 and Repository patterns.

Also, I've read about IoC and dependency injection, but I have yet to find a good single resource that puts it all together in a hands-on approach.

Can anyone suggest any good books that show best practices by example and also when to use certain design patterns over another?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Pro ASP.Net MVC 2 Framework](http://apress.com/book/view/1430228865) is great.

[Check out what Scott Guthrie has to say about this book](http://www.amazon.com/review/R72GUUN3I9QUA/ref=cm_cr_dp_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0041N3H1G&nodeID=133140011&tag=&linkCode=)

Comment: +1 I like the way it's written with Unit Testing and TDD

Comment: ScottGu's review definitely tells me this book might be what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for Pro MVC, excellent book.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [ASP.NET MVC 2 in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193518279X)

Comment: This is highly recommended based on the needs of the question. They do a great job of putting the puzzle pieces together to make an enterprise level MVC app.

Comment: I have read both this book and Paul Sanderson's book.  Both I would recommend.  It is worth noting that Manning regularly does really good deals on their books directly from their website (at the time of this question being asked its 35% off until Nov 2nd with the coupon "n235").

Comment: @cfeduke - Can you link the site?

Comment: For Manning its manning.com - at first glance the website may be questionable, but they do have account.manning.com which is fairly functional.

Answer (score 0):

I like Dino's style [Programming Microsoft® ASP.NET MVC](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Books.aspx?Id=13989&locale=en-us).
In fact I think that you will read all three books, they are all great: Framework, Action and Programming ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would 2nd the recommendation for Pro ASP.Net MVC 2 Framework. Very thorough and well written.

Steve Sanderson the author has also done a series of videos on MVC for [www.tekpub.com](http://www.tekpub.com)

John

Comment: The up vote is generally how we "second" answers around these parts ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although not strictly focused on MVC, I would highly recommend [Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470292784) by Scott Millet.

The book is filled with detailed examples (Many use ASP.NET MVC) relating to the repository pattern, units of work, IoC and many other popular design patterns. It's also a great introduction for those wanting to learn how to program to patterns.